# sh file to construct mongo document

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

My document structure looks like this:

```
{"name":"John", "age":32, ...other fields}
```

All other fields need not be initialized, only name and age. I want to make a script that takes in name and number

```
./client.sh John 32
```

and in the script, it will do something like

```
db.client.insert({"name":$1,"age":$2});
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `achieve`? It looks like you've mostly answered this from the question alone.

Comment: @arco444 the script didnt work, and that's where I need. unless you're saying that the script above actually worked?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `didn't work`? Which bit didn't work? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35202905/edit) the question to provide more details about where it failed and ideally include the whole script you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example script that works

```
 #!/bin/bash

 if [ $# -lt 2 ]
 then
   echo "USAGE: $0 name age"
   exit 1
 fi

 mongo <<EOF
 use test
 db.client.insert({"name":"$1", "age":$2})
 db.client.find()
 EOF
```

It assumes that `mongo` is installed and in your path and that you have the `client` collection in the `test` database.

A sample run below

```
hduser@localhost:~/temp$ ./mongo_ins.sh "overflow" 20
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: test
switched to db test
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56b35d134c24bf7c1190cfb3"), "name" : "Stack", "age" : 1     }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56b35dabe23223802ea3fa61"), "name" : {  }, "age" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56b35ebbd69a0abeeb817fe3"), "name" : "overflow", "age" : 20 }
bye
```

Hope this helps